# display data from different table every refresh on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 3 tables with same structure. the tables name are :
1. life
2. nature
3. beauty

nah I want to show the data random. example first refresh data from life, then when I refresh page will change to data from nature table.

example:
if I just one table it will be SELECT * from life order by RAND(); But I want the merge of life,nature and beauty table will show random data

please help me

Comment: how could we help? there's nothing to look at!? What have you tried?

Comment: if just one table it will be SELECT * from life order by RAND();
But I want the merge of life,nature and beauty table will show random data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display random data from across all the tables you could do a union on all of them

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM life
UNION
SELECT * FROM nature
UNION
SELECT * FROM beauty
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
";
```

Otherwise if you need to have a next table picked every time you refresh you should start a session, and based on that session variable you change the table.

```
session_start();
$tables = ['life', 'nature', 'beauty'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['current_table']))
{
     $_SESSION['current_table'] = $tables[0];
}
else
{
     $current_index = array_search($_SESSION['current_table'], $tables];
     $next_index = current_index + 1;
     if($next_index >= count($tables)) 
     {
           $next_index = 0;
     }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM" . $tables[$next_index];
```

Comment: Hi..
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM life
UNION
SELECT * FROM nature
UNION
SELECT * FROM beauty
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
";
thats code still doesn't work, data can't display

Comment: Good to know! Glad to help!